# Set dropdownParent of Existing Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, jquery-select2

I have a `Select2` that is a autocomplete widget from Django. Due to a known issue with Firefox not focusing on the `Select2` when inside a modal, I use this line to add the `dropdownParent`:

```
$("#id_project").select2({dropdownParent: $(".modal-body")});
```

This causes the initial definition of the `Select2` (including the data url) to be lost. How do I set the `dropdownParent` of an existing `Select2`?

Current JS code to load my modal:

```
  var loadForm = function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: btn.attr("data-url"),
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function () {
        $("#modal-task").modal("show");
      },
      success: function (data) {
        $("#modal-task .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
        //$("#id_project").select2({dropdownParent: $(".modal-body")});
        $('#id_targetDate').datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
        $('#id_completedDate').datepicker({ maxDate: new Date});
      }
    });
  };
```

**Update:** I can fully define my `Select2` with JS:

```
$("#id_project").select2({
    dropdownParent: $('.modal-body'),
    placeholder: "00000",
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
        url: "http://localhost:8000/full/url/to/autocomplete/data",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "get",
    }
});
```

However, this causes all of the nodes to loaded up front, rather than loading each one if it's clicked on.

Comment: Are you instantiating your select2 multiple times?

Comment: yes, it is first defined as a widget in a Django form. adding the JS to add `dropdownParent` instantiates it again

Comment: can you just add your arguments of `{dropdownParent: $(".modal-body")}` to the widget defined by Django form?

Comment: not that i'm aware of. i can add HTML attributes, but dropdownParent doesn't fit that category

Comment: can you define an init method, then apply the dropdownParent on `this`?

Comment: sounds promising - do you mind explaining a bit more? i added my modal code, in case that's helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the `dropdownParent` attribute while initializing the object in Django as follows in **forms.py**:

```
"id_project": autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
    url="http://localhost:8000/full/url/to/autocomplete/data", # except that this should really be a Django reverse URL
    attrs={
        "style": "width:50%;",
        "data-dropdown-parent": ".modal-body",
    },
)
```

The documentation is here:
https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#passing-options-to-select2